# Android Activity: Input number, press button, pass from the xml to the class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, user-input

Hello!
Trying to input a number to the EditText field, press the calc531button and have that number get to the inputDouble variable.

xml:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:id="@+id/inputField"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title5"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:id="@+id/calcBtn"
    android:onClick="inputField" />
```

java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_five);

    View.OnClickListener calcButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textHold = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputField);
            stringHold = textHold.getText().toString();
            inputDouble = Double.parseDouble(stringHold);
        }
    };
```

logcat Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method squat1RMinputField(View)
.........
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: inputField [class android.view.View]
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling onClickListener to the same button twice and implementing only once.

If you already have defined `android:onClick=""inputField""` inside the xml having `Button`, you just need to implement the `inputField` method in your activity.

```
public void inputField(View v){
    textHold = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputField);
    stringHold = textHold.getText().toString();
    inputDouble = Double.parseDouble(stringHold);
}
```

and remove the `View.OnClickListener calcButton...` from your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Apurva ! This got me 95% of the way there but I had to add the "View v" method header and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you have specified the method name as inputField in your xml file. You should implement the same method in your activity

**method 1**

```
public void inputField (View v)
{
  textHold = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputField);
            stringHold = textHold.getText().toString();
            inputDouble = Double.parseDouble(stringHold);
}
```

Remove the onclick method.

**method 2**

```
Button calcButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calcBtn);
calcButton.setOnClickListener(calcBtn);
```

Where calcBtn is  your onClickListener,and remove `android:onClick="inputField"` line from your xml.

Comment: Hi Preethi! I went semi-backwards from your solution, I didn't use the "method 2" and kept the android:onClick, but your method is exactly what mine looks like and now it WORKS. Cheers!

Comment: @jackEarlyDays method 1 was the exact answer you were looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your xml should be:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:id="@+id/inputField"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title5"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:id="@+id/calcBtn"
android:onClick="inputField" />
```

and in Your activity you should write your method inputField(View v)

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_five);
      }

      //Your method to handle click
      public void inputField (View v){  
      textHold = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputField);
                stringHold = textHold.getText().toString();
                inputDouble = Double.parseDouble(stringHold);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! It looks so simple now, was doing my head in for the last two hours!

Comment: @jackEarlyDays Not at all. I remember how I begin and I understand your problems, good luck!)